# Node.js MVC Routing Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller

I'm implementing an MVC pattern in Node.js and I have it setup as described below. I'm getting a page on localhost which is just hanging and '/' in my console.log as I have a logger.

app.js

```
var express  = require("express");
var partials = require("express-partials");
var cookies  = require("cookie-parser");
var session  = require("express-session");
var uuid     = require("node-uuid");
var parser   = require("body-parser");
var csrf     = require("csurf");
var compress = require("express-html-minify");

var logger   = require("./controllers/logger");
var errors   = require("./controllers/errors");
var utility  = require("./controllers/utility");

var routes   = require("./routes");

var app  = new express();
var port = 80;

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.set("view options", {defaultLayout: "layout"});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.use(logger.log);
app.use(partials());
app.use(cookies());
app.use(session({secret: uuid.v1(), resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}));
app.use(parser.json());
app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(csrf());
app.use(utility.csrf);
app.use(compress);
app.use(routes.controller);

app.use(errors.error);
app.use(errors.notfound);

app.listen(port);
console.log("app listening on port " + port);
```

./routes/index.js

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

var controllers = require("../controllers");

exports.controller = function() {
    app.get("/", controllers.index);
    app.get("/login", controllers.login);
    app.post("/login", controllers.process);
    app.get("/reset", controllers.reset);
    app.get("/whoops", controllers.whoops);
};
```

./controllers/index.js

```
exports.index = function(request, response) {
    response.render("index", {layout: "layout", title: "Index", cookie: JSON.stringify(request.cookies), session: JSON.stringify(request.session)});
};

exports.login = function(request, response) {
    response.render("login", {layout: "layout", title: "Login", cookie: JSON.stringify(request.cookies), session: JSON.stringify(request.session)});
};

exports.process = function(request, response) {
    response.render("process", {layout: "layout", title: "Process", username: request.body.username});
};

exports.reset = function(request, response) {
    response.render("reset", {layout: "layout", title: "Reset"});
};

exports.whoops = function(request, response) {
    response.render("whoops", {layout: "layout", title: "Whoops"});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of changes required to fix the router issue.

**File "app.js" changes:-**

1) Change the routes as mentioned below though it is not mandatory to include index in the path. This way you are clearly referring the index file.

```
var routes   = require("./routes/index");
```

2) Replace "app.use(routes.controller)" code with the below code

```
app.use('/', routes);
```

**File "routes/index.js" changes:-**

Replace the file content as mentioned below:-

Now, the requests will be routed to respective methods in "controllers/index.js" as per the URL.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

var controllers = require("../controllers/index");
router.get("/", controllers.index);
router.get("/login", controllers.login);
router.post("/login", controllers.process);
router.get("/reset", controllers.reset);
router.get("/whoops", controllers.whoops);

module.exports = router;
```